# Currently Supported Way to Elevate Privileges

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Can somebody shed some light on the currently supported and recommend ways to elevate privileges in a helper tool?

From my understanding the following ways are not the Apple supported way to do it:

- setuid
- AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()

I am looking for a way to be able to run /usr/sbin/softwareupdate and place a launchd in /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Any documentation or sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, Apple recommends avoiding setuid binaries and AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges, for security reasons. The recommend approach seems to be to have a privileged helper tool run (on demand) by launchd, communicating with that helper from your application by IPC over a Unix domain socket. The privileged helper would be run by launchd with the necessary privileges

The [BetterAuthorizationSample sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample) gives an example of doing this.

Comment: no, the SMJobBless sample code gives an example of doing that... teh BetterAuthorizationSample uses other (older) methods to escalate privileges. The SMJobBless code is much clearer IMHO, and is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The new, officially-supported, introduced-in-10.6 method is called SMJobBless(). However, there is very little documentation on it; a cursory Google search showed a handful of blog posts.